# HVAC Wiring: Any reasons for one zone to be wired different from others?

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, valve

In the course of attempting to add a C wire for some new wi-fi thermostats I noticed something odd about the existing wiring on my system. My system has four zones: Hot Water, Main, Guest, and Master. The hot water, main, and guest are wired as one would expect. But the Master zone is different from all the rest. See diagram:

[image]

My inclination is to rewire the Master Zone circuit to match the others. But before I do so I wanted to make sure there isn't some reason foreign to me for doing it this way.

Thanks in advance!

Oliver

Comment: I'm surprised that you aren't having issues with what's connected between R and C on the other two 'stats.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I forgot to diagram it, but I had to switch the R and W wires at the thermostats on Main and Guest when I added the C to make it all work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Someone wired your thermostat in rather...backwards

Normally, the R terminal on a thermostat goes to the 24VAC end of the transformer, the W terminal on a thermostat goes to the TH terminal on whatever the thermostat is controlling, and the TR terminal on whatever is getting controlled goes back to the other (0VAC) end of the transformer, which is also where the C wire connects.

This is analogous to having a light switch in the hot wire to a light, with the R wire being the hot feed from the panel, the W wire being the switched hot to the light, the C wire being the neutral, the thermostat taking the place of the switch, and the device under control assuming the role of the light.

However, in your case, the installer routed R to the 0VAC (C-wire) end of the transformer, and connected the TR terminal on the device under control to the 24VAC (R-wire) end of the transformer.  This still works, as the switch and the device are in series, and neither is polarized because we're dealing with AC here -- its analogous to having a switch in the neutral wire.  (The 120VAC version is against Code, despite the fact it works electrically, because it's a great way to get bit by 60Hz while changing a lightbulb.)

However, if your thermostat needs a C wire, things start to fall down a bit.  Connecting C back to the 0VAC (C-wire) terminal on the transformer will make any of the fancy things on the thermostat that need the C-wire to work simply *not work* because there's no voltage between R and C in that case.  Instead, in order to get the fancy stuff to work, you have to connect C on the thermostat to the 24VAC (R-wire) end of the transformer.  This will still work, most likely, because it's an AC system and thus not polarized.  However, it's going to be awkward for the next poor bloke who has to service this system!

It should be relatively simple to switch the wiring around at the junction where the wires for the master thermostat and it's associated zone valve are located.  The R-wire from the 'stat should go to the 24VAC (R) end of the transformer like the other R-wires, and the wire from the TR terminal on the zone valve should go to the 0VAC (C) end of the transformer, just like how the other zone valves are wired up.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid that it was wired that way for some special reason beyond my basic understanding and that if I changed it, it would be light's out for the heat.

Answer (score 0):

These are all AC voltages. Basically, you have a transformer output, a thermostatic switch, and a motor driver (actually a relay) all in a loop. It doesn't matter which order the three items are wired, so either of your two wiring plans should work fine. (I presume that your heating system has been working fine.)

The only reason to regularize the wiring is to lessen confusion in the future, which is a true benefit, but since you have this quite clear diagram it would be just as valuable, and much easier, to just post it by the furnace.

Comment: Thanks, I would be lying if I said it didn't take several drafts to get the diagram right. If I leave the Master wiring as is, where would I make the connection to add a C wire for the thermostat?

Comment: @Oliver -- the C terminal on the transformer (all the other C wires connect there too)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- If I do that, leaving the Master zone wired as, will it cause the zone valve motor (and in turn the endswitch and boiler) to activate every time the thermostat draws power utilizing the C wire?

Comment: Oh, wait...huh.  Let me put a full answer together for you